# use fix route in asp.net core api

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm converting my code to Asp.net core 3.1 in a web api project. my code is something similar to bellow:

[image]

When i call http://localhost:44307/PersonDetails I would like to get "Result1" and when i call http://localhost:44307/Person/2207 i should get "result2".

The first route works as i expected but for the second one, I get 404. it works if i call http://localhost:44307/PersonDetails/Person/2207 but it is not what i expected.

Appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/Person/{personId}")]
public ActionResult<Person> Get([FromQuery]int personId)
{
    return Ok("result2");
}
```

When you add `~` before it, it will ignore the route attribute on your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
```

when you use a route on your controllers, all child actions will use that. so in this case, because your controller name is `PersonDetails` you have to enter the controller name in your URLs.

but, you can use this trick :

step1: remove this line:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
```

step2: add `PersonDetails` to your Get method

```cs
[Route("PersonDetails")]
Public ActionResult Get()
```